# How to fix "Unexpected data received." with ahk module Python?

Tags: python, automation, autohotkey

I am trying to use the ahk module with Python and every time I try to use it it simply raises an error that says "ahk._sync.transport.AHKProtocolError: Unexpected data received. This is usually the result of an unhandled error in the AHK process."

I have tried:

```
from ahk import AHK

ahk = AHK(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\v2\AutoHotKey.exe")
```

This code raises the exception, it was working fine yesterday but I reinstalled the package and now it is no longer working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read closely in the section about `Non-Python dependencies` in the GitHub repository it clearly states that:

> Note: this should be AutoHotkey V1. AutoHotkey V2 is not yet supported.

Since the path you provided has `v2` in it, I am assuming you are trying to use AutoHotkey v2.
The problem should be solved if you provide the path to an AutoHotkey **v1** executable.